# Xcode linker error on iPhone app both in Device and simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4

Hello Developers I get one linker Error when i am trying to create the Build  any idea

Here Are The Error

> error: unknown argument: '-fobjc-nonfragile-abi2'
>       Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have added this (-fobjc-nonfragile-abi2) Linker Flag inside "Other Linker Flags" of your project settings then remove it, according to latest LLVM compiler this is default setting.